# Memory leak when using smart pointers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Consider the following function:

```
unique_ptr<char> f(const wstring key, const unsigned int length)
{
    assert(length <= key.length());
    const wstring suffix = key.substr(length, key.length() - length);
    const size_t outputSize = suffix.length() + 1; // +1 for null terminator
    char * output = new char[outputSize];
    size_t charsConverted = 0;
    const wchar_t * outputWide = suffix.c_str();
    wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, output, outputSize, outputWide, suffix.length());
    return unique_ptr<char>(output);
}
```

The intent here is to accept a wstring, select `length` characters from the end, and return them as a C-style string that's wrapped in a unique_ptr (as required by another library - I certainly didn't chose that type :)).

One of my peers said in passing that he thinks this leaks memory, but he didn't have time to elaborate, and I don't see it. Can anybody spot it, and if so explain how I ought to fix it? I probably have my blinders on.

Comment: What if `wcstombs_s` fails?

Comment: Given a choice, it would make far more sense to return a `std::string`. But it sounds like you don't get a choice on that.

Comment: RAII: the result of new should be placed *directly* in unique_ptr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not necessarily a leak, but it is undefined behavior. You created the `char` array using `new[]` but the `unique_ptr<char>` will call `delete`, and not `delete[]` to free the memory. Use `unique_ptr<char[]>` instead.

Also, your conversion may not always behave the way you want it to. You should make 2 calls to [`wcstombs_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7wzt4be.aspx), in the first one pass `nullptr` as the second argument. This will return the number of characters required in the output string.

```
wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, nullptr, 0, outputWide, suffix.length());
```

Check the return value, and then use the result stored in `charsConverted` to allocate the output buffer.

```
auto output = std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[charsConverted]);
// now use output.get() to get access to the raw pointer
```